# Problem when trying to access my HardDrive (Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS)

Tags: hard-drive, 22.04

I recently encountered the following error when trying to access my files on my hard drive from my PC running Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS:

[image: screenshot of error]

Previously, I tried to access a backup through Rescuezilla. I don't know if this  is connected to my problem. I was able to access the hard drive from another PC, so the hard drive itself is fine.

Here is the output of `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda`:

[image: screenshot of text]

Comment: With the drive connected, can you run `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda` on the command line for us?  Add the output from the command to your post as an edit, please, and not as a screenshot of text.

Comment: @ThomasWard I added it. I'm sorry, but I had to post it as a screenshot, because I couldn't paste it as code. 